# which part is causing "SIGSEGV" error and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, c++11

i am facing a runtime error "SIGSEGV" in this code , i searched about it and what i got is ,this error is caused due to segmentation fault , i am not able to find segmentation fault in this .i want to know how to fix this error .

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int counti(int A[],int N)
{
    int d=0,i;

        for(i=0;i<N;++i)
        {
            if(A[i]==A[N-1])
            {
                d++;
            }
        }

        return d;
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    cout<<" enter total number of test cases ";
    cin>>T;

    while(T--)
    {
        int N,d;

        cout<<" enter the value of N between (1 and 16)";
        cin>>N;

        int A[16]={0,0,1,0,2,0,2,2,1,6,0,5,0,2,6,5},i;


        d=counti(A,N);



        cout<<d<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the input you used and which caused the segmentation fault.

Comment: the program is giving runtime error SIGSEGV .

Comment: Yes, I understood that. What did you type into the console when it asked you `enter total number of test cases` and later when it asked you `enter the value of N between (1 and 16)` to make it generate the segmentation fault? Please answer this with precision, including any enter presses and whitespaces.

Comment: i ran the program and it showed your program is having run time error ,it didn't took any input .

Comment: Where did it show that? What was the complete, exact error message? Are you running this program on your own system or on some online site?

Comment: i am running this program on online site and when i am running this program in output box it is showing SIGSEGV just this

Comment: Then there is no way to help you, because we don't know what input that site gave to your program. You can generate a SIGSEV by, for example, inputting 42 for the second question.

Comment: i was trying to debugg the code and what i found was ```for(i=0;i<N;++i)
        {
            if(A[i]==A[N-1])
            {
                d++;
            }
        }``` is causing SIGSEGV but i don't know what's wrong with this

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault occurs when you try to access some undefined memory. As your debug observation says it is happening somewhere in `for(i=0;i<N;++i) { if(A[i]==A[N-1]) { d++; } }`, may be you are trying to access some undefined memory via `A[N-1]` ( ie, when `N =17` ) you are trying to access `A[16]`which may cause segmentation fault (this will happen for any value of `N` greater than 16, so keep some checking to avoid this). The input file may contain any value, it is you who need to keep the boundary checks.

Comment: @pkchamp should be ok for 1 to 16, i said it based on your last comment, i can't debug this for you currently, please debug the code and see what breaks the code.